# Why not put ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush on every component?

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection, angular-changedetection

As far as I understand, declaring `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` on a component means that it will only update when one of its input values is changed specifically, rather than checking for changes when its parent(s) values change.  If that is the case, why wouldn't `OnPush` be the default setting.  Is there a case where we wouldn't want this behaviour?

Comment: I've asked the same question one hour ago. hope that helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53426412/should-use-changedetectionstrategy-onpush-for-eveything

Comment: What are the chances!  It helps a lot.  Thanks