# Why is my ChangeDetectorRef not updating a list in the view?

Tags: angular, change-detector-ref

I have a simple list in the view with hardcoded data in the contoler:

**errorcount.component.html**

```
    ...
    <tr *ngFor="let errorcounter of errorCounterList">
      <td>{{errorcounter.date}}</td>
      <td style="text-align:right;">{{errorcounter.count}}</td>
    </tr>
    ....
```

**errorcount.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';

export interface ErrorCounter {
  id: number,
  error_id: number,
  date: string,
  count: number
};

@Component({
  selector: 'app-errorcount',
  templateUrl: './errorcount.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./errorcount.component.css'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class ErrorcountComponent implements OnInit {

  errorCounterList: ErrorCounter[];

  constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this.errorCounterList = [
      { id: 1, error_id: 1, date: '20230101', count: 201 },
      { id: 2, error_id: 2, date: '20230102', count: 321 },
      { id: 3, error_id: 3, date: '20230103', count: 431 },
      { id: 4, error_id: 1, date: '20230104', count: 541 },
      { id: 5, error_id: 2, date: '20230105', count: 651 },
      { id: 6, error_id: 3, date: '20230106', count: 561 },
      { id: 7, error_id: 1, date: '20230107', count: 471 },
      { id: 8, error_id: 2, date: '20230108', count: 381 },
      { id: 9, error_id: 3, date: '20230109', count: 282 },
      { id: 10, error_id: 1, date: '20230110', count: 184 },
    ];
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.ref.detectChanges();
  }

  filterCounters(id: number) {
    this.errorCounterList = this.errorCounterList.filter(f => f.error_id == id);
    this.ref.markForCheck();
  }

}
```

I call filterCounters() and the debugger shows thr filtered list but the detectChanges does not change the items in the view.

Any help would get me sleeping again.

Comment: Try using `detectChanges()` instead of `markForCheck()` since you're using `OnPush` change detection and it will not get triggered until data-bound variables are changed. This SO thread may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41364469/1331040

Comment: For me is working, look https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kazmjn?file=src%2Fmain.ts, without using `ChangeDetectorRef`, the problem lives somewhere else

Comment: Where do you call `filterCounters`?

Comment: Hey leonmain. I think my problem is from where I am calling the filterCounters. i have one view with two components in material cards tring to refresh one another. I have stumbled on angular zones. Will try to implement: https://mokkapps.de/blog/the-last-guide-for-angular-change-detection-you-will-ever-need/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To whom it may help, the only way I got this to work was to use LocalStorage:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    localStorage.setItem('errorCounterList', JSON.stringify(this.errorCounterList));
}
filterCounterList(id: number) { 
    localStorage.removeItem('errorCounterList');localStorage.setItem('errorCounterList',JSON.stringify(this.errorCounterList.filter(f => f.error_id == id)));
}
getCounterList() {
    this.errorCounterList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('errorCounterList') ?? '');
    return this.errorCounterList;
}
```

That solved my imidiate problem, but it will not always fit as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I all ready repicate your app in the follow stackblitz link:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/my-angular-project-wdllee?file=app/login/login.component.ts

And works perfectly, you need call your filter function:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.ref.detectChanges();
    this.filterCounters(1); // => You need call your function
  }
```

You dont need "`ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`" is better if you only call your function when you need refresh your view.

Please read this article:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53426605/9420442